# Polymer and Elm vdom inconsistencies

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, elm

Given:

```
swiper =
     div []
         [ node "swiper-node"
             [ class "block" ]
             [ div [ id "swiperContainer" ]
                 [ div [ class "swiper-wrapper" ]
                     [ div [ class "swiper-slide", style [ ( "height", "400px" ), ( "background", "gray" ) ] ] [ text "slide1" ]
                     , div [ class "swiper-slide", style [ ( "height", "400px" ), ( "background", "gray" ) ] ] [ text "slide2" ]
                     , div [ class "swiper-slide", style [ ( "height", "400px" ), ( "background", "gray" ) ] ] [ text "slide3" ]
                     , div [ class "swiper-slide", style [ ( "height", "400px" ), ( "background", "gray" ) ] ] [ text "slide4" ]
                     ]
                 ]
             ]
         ]
```

---

```
<dom-module id="swiper-node">

   <template></template>

   <style>
   </style>

   <script>
     (function () {
       Polymer({
         is: 'swiper-node',
       });
     }());
   </script>
</dom-module>
```

The rendered HTML is:

[image]

Notice the empty `swiper-node`.

The interesting thing is that this happens when the app starts AND `swiper` is IN the Elm dom.

However, if

1. the app starts
2. AND the `swiper` is NOT in the elm dom
3. AND on some user event, the `swiper` is added to the elm dom

it's rendered correctly.

---

After going through [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/elm-discuss/8Q2xwRh6UYc/tGem48QjAQAJ), I did the same configuration of:

```
 window.Polymer = {
   dom: 'shadow',
   lazyRegister: true
 };
```

And in both cases:

- when app starts with `swiper`
- when `swiper` is added later on user event (click)

this is the rendered html:

[image]

Altho we've reached consistency, the `swiper-node` is not being rendered. U know how when you hover a dom element in the inspector, it highlights in the render window? Well, hovering on any of the  `swiper-node` children, shows nothing.

I'm only utilizing Polymer abstraction/component so i can utilize a js library within Elm in a nice way. So don't assume great Polymer or web-components knowledge on my end.

Comment: swiper-node content is hidden by the Shadow DOM. Use 'shady' instead of 'shadow'

Comment: @Supersharp shady is used implicitly without the configuration. The actual issue revolved around missing the `<content>` tag. I'll do a quick writeup soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `content` inside the `template` so that the component becomes:

```
<dom-module id="swiper-node">

   <template><content></content></template>

   <style>
   </style>

   <script>
     (function () {
       Polymer({
         is: 'swiper-node',
       });
     }());
   </script>
</dom-module>
```

::curl_up_and_cry::